# document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent") - get keycode for manually created event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using the custom input event found @ http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event..

The trouble is that I am not able to get the keycode for the event. Any ideas?

Comment: Well I'll let Andy E himself provide a definitive answer, but I seriously doubt it's going to be possible to get a keycode value reliably in all cases, in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cure..

in the end, I updated the following lines;-

```
 else if (onprop)
    $(this).bind("onpropertychange", handler);
```

to;-

```
 else if (onprop)
    $(this).bind("keypress", function(e){
    handler.call(this, e)
    });
```